# Firefox 29 + Tree Style Tabs + Tab Mix Plus: Open new tab with double click

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

After updating to FF29, I can't open a new tab when clicking on the empty area below the tabs.

Edit: This is confirmed to be a change made by FF29, no addons have anything to do with it. See answer below.

I have Tree Style Tabs displayed vertically on the left side of the window. Opening new tab on double click is a function of Tab Mix Plus, so I am not sure if FF29 or Tree Style Tabs is responsible for the change. Does anyone know an alternative?

When I disable TST, I also cannot double click to open on the empty part of the tab row. TMP has the option to disable resize when you click this - so it appears to be an incompatibility between FF29 and TMP

I've heard that others have the problem without any plugins, so it's possible that this is simply a FF29 bug or "feature"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually this is not a problem of Tab Mix Plus or Tree Style Tab, this is a "feature" of FF 29 (sounds like a regression to me). Check out [this comment](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/reviews/580072/) by the developer of TST.

I've searched for the solution for a while and found [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/). It allows us to restore those parts of the UI we like from pre-Australis. The one you are interested in is located on the 'Special' tab. Also note that I had to change tab style to the 'Curved (Australis)' in CTR for proper rendering of the Tab Tree, I'm using Sidebar style for TST and it was horrible without that Australis setting.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Firefox extension [Classic Theme Restorer (Customize Australis)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/), you can set it over its GUI (screenshot of its german version)

[image]

or over `about:config`

```
extensions.classicthemerestorer.dblclnewtab: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Tab Mix Plus but not TST and I can open a new tab by double clicking on the empty tab space on the right of the open tabs.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Tab Mix Plus then disable it, as it's causing the tab issues.